# postfix ignores .forward file if it's a link

Tags: postfix

I use a .forward file (with a pipe) and postfix respects the file and does the pipe for my mail delivery (since my "allow_mail_to_commands" setting is the default, which includes "forward")

But if I try to move the .forward file to a new (and readable!) location with a symlink, the postfix no longer uses the .forward file and attempts a regular mail delivery.

Is this for some sort of security reason?  Is there a way to force postfix to use the .forward file even if it is behind a symlink?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's for a security reason. A `.forward` file which is a link can be subverted several ways (mount overlay, `IFS`, ...).

Check the Postfix documentation.

Comment: This is a decent half answer..  but I did check the postfix docs (I should have mentioned that in the question) and did not see any reference to this or if there's an option to turn it off.  I'm the only user on my system, and the way I organize this, links would be extremely useful.